# producing an moderncv head with the article class

Tags: fonts, moderncv, article

moderncv generates a beautiful header, which i want to have in the `article` class. I want an exact copy of the moderncv result, with the same fonts, the same color, etc. Unfortunately, the [moderncv source files](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/master/moderncv.cls) are very confusing to me, so i don't know where it was specified.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\lastname{Benjamin}
\firstname{Franklin}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

produces: [image: result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the cleanest way to do it, but

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{185,185,185}
\definecolor{darkgray}{RGB}{115,115,115}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushright}
\color{lightgray}{\Huge Bejamin}
\color{darkgray}{\Huge Franklin}
\end{flushright}
\vspace{-0.5cm}
\textcolor{lightgray}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: ModernCV header as Article header]